# Angular js - basic toggle of additional object values

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I would like to output a basic list of names, and below the list display some text.  This text should only be displayed once you've clicked on an item and it should toggle when selecting another.

What I've got so far

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="contacts">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="person in people | orderBy:'name'">
                <a  href="#">{{person.name}}</a>
                <span>{{person.age}}</span>

            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="desc">
        <!-- I  would like to output the descriptions here -->
        </div>
   </div>
</div>   
<script>
var contacts = function($scope) {
    $scope.people = [
        {name:"paul", age:30, desc:"this is a description"},
        {name:"jax", age:33, desc:"this is another description right here"},
        {name:"yoda", age:33, desc:"final description goes here"},
        {name:"steve", age:53, desc:"jsut kidding - one more."}
    ];
};
</script>
```

I'm pretty sure I should be using ng-click and possible the model etc but this simple task is doing my head in.  I'm able to do a basic show and hide below the link (though not sure about toggling them).

Super new to angular, please excuse me if this seems like a retarded request.
Looking for a super clean, quick and easy way to do this. Any input would be great.

Comment: Add a http://plnkr.co/ it will be much easier for people to give a working solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are not silly questions; at some point we were all newbies :)

**Controller**

```
var contacts = function($scope) {
    $scope.people = [
        {name:"paul", age:30, desc:"this is a description"},
        {name:"jax", age:33, desc:"this is another description right here"},
        {name:"yoda", age:33, desc:"final description goes here"},
        {name:"steve", age:53, desc:"jsut kidding - one more."}
    ];
  $scope.selectedPersonDescription = null;
  $scope.selectPerson = function(person) {
    $scope.selectedPersonDescription = person.desc;
  }
};
```

**View**

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="contacts">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="person in people | orderBy:'name'", ng-click="selectPerson(person)">
                <a  href="#">{{person.name}}</a>
                <span>{{person.age}}</span>

            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="desc">
        {{ selectedPersonDescription }}
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: intuitively I had this - but wasn't sure what to stick where - I want to up vote your answer 9000+ times for this, thank you. perfectly simple and elegant - amazing!  the challenge here for me is actually "getting" angulars simplicity

Comment: @pushplaybang, that is often the problem for most people. :) What helps me is to just say what things do, then write that in whatever part of the app I'm talking about. For example, if I said "It displays a list of names", then write that in your html - `ng-repeat="name in names"`. And so forth with buttons and all (don't worry about writing a function yet, just write `ng-click="selectPerson(name)"` and continue. Then in the controller, you'll know you need this `$scope.names = myService.getNames()`. And now you know you need a service to get names for you. See how easy?

Comment: for sure, I think thats a great approach to adopt, I'm really excited about building javascript apps, but its definitely a paradigm shift using angular, (one that I quite like).